script that hides/unhides columns, sometimes works/sometimes doesn't
This script sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.
Majority of the time it does, but any ideas as to why it shouldn't?
If it doesn't work, running the script a second time works.
function toggleB10() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const value1 = sheet.getRange("E10").getValue();
  const value2 = sheet.getRange("F10").getValue();
  if (scriptProperties.getProperty('hidden') == 'false') {
    scriptProperties.setProperty('hidden', true); 
    sheet.hideColumns(value1,value2);
  }
  else {
    scriptProperties.setProperty('hidden', false);
    sheet.showColumns(value1,value2); 
  }
}


Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Make sure to add the expected input and output so that the community may replicate your issue easily.

I don't think it is specifically the script. I've adapted this over time, but the basic premise was to have a button that would toggle hide/unhide columns. It just seems to be an unreliable process.

The main reason why you encountered this problem is because you did not set the value of  property at first that's why it will run on the second time when the function is triggered.

The value of property could either be true or false to start with, that's the difficulty.

Seeing how the function works you can use this as reference before and after the execution. function being Activated  First Time, function being Activated Second Time.

Please add more details. Could you tell us when it works and when it doesn't?

Setting a Property Value
Seeing how the function works you can use this as reference before and after the execution. function being Activated  First Time, function being Activated Second Time.
To make this work I added a ternary condition for you to add in your code so that on the first execution the hidden property has already a value.
Code Line to add:
scriptProperties.getProperty('hidden') == null ? scriptProperties.setProperty('hidden', false) : null;

Whole Script:
function toggleB10() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const value1 = sheet.getRange("E10").getValue();
  const value2 = sheet.getRange("F10").getValue();

  scriptProperties.getProperty('hidden') == null ? scriptProperties.setProperty('hidden', false) : null;
  
  if (scriptProperties.getProperty('hidden') == 'false') {
    scriptProperties.setProperty('hidden', true); 
    sheet.hideColumns(value1,value2);
  } else {
    scriptProperties.setProperty('hidden', false);
    sheet.showColumns(value1,value2); 
  }
}

Reference:
Conditional (ternary) operator

Many thanks @Lime Husky, but I still experience the same issue, especially with more than one script... Your script above on B10, but then i'll be running a second instance on B11, a third on B12, etc. I tried an OnOpen() script to set the property to hidden, but that didn't work either.

You're welcome! I hope this issue helps and solves your case.

Your comment regarding not setting the property value to start with was most valuable.  By adding an OnOpen function to set the property to hidden, at first it didn't work because I had amended the original script to try a different approach, but after resetting back to original script with the OnOpen function, everything feels more robust.

If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer
